# How to add several tables tables on c# code?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Creating an application and can't figure out how I can create multiple tables in an sql database by clicking on a form? I have 2 connection. 
1 connection for create database,
2 connection for create table in database

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection connstringsql = new SqlConnection(constring);

    //for create table in database
    static string create =
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test.Properties.Settings.Setting1"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection connscreate = new SqlConnection(create);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //create table
        connscreate.Open();
        string sqlqueryone = "CREATE TABLE test";
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlqueryone, connscreate);
        connscreate.Close();
    }
```

When I click on the button in the base to create several tables.

Comment: What's wrong with the code that you have?  What is it doing or not doing?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Do not reuse instances of `SqlConnection`; this brings nothing but headaches. Create them as needed and keep them in `using` blocks with as small a scope as reasonable (ditto for `SqlCommand`). An `SqlConnection` represents a handle to a pooled connection; you do not need to optimize their creation. Also, obviously, your `CREATE TABLE` statement as given is invalid; a table must have at least one column.

Comment: Also noting you're not actually executing `sqlcomm`

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't want to have your application create table(s).  This is something that you would want to do as part of the setup/deployment of an application.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more background info as to why your trying to do this? There might be better solutions than programmatically creating your db tables.

Comment: @rory.ap no error, but i cant create another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void createDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "Data Source =HALLR3C04;User ID=sa;Password=123456;";
        SqlConnection connstringsql = new SqlConnection(constring);

        //create table
        connstringsql.Open();
        string sqlqueryone = "CREATE DATABASE " + textBoxDatabaseName.Text;
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlqueryone, connstringsql);
        sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connstringsql.Close();

        listBoxDatabases.Items.Add(textBoxDatabaseName.Text);
    }

    private void createTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = $"Data Source =HALLR3C04;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog = {listBoxDatabases.SelectedItem.ToString()};Password=123456;";
        SqlConnection connstringsql = new SqlConnection(constring);

        //create table
        connstringsql.Open();
        string sqlqueryone = $@"create table {textBoxTableName.Text}
                                (
                                    Id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                                    Name VARCHAR(50)
                                ) ";
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlqueryone, connstringsql);
        sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connstringsql.Close();
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: always put `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` inside a `using`. Never teach bad idea's to people that are still learning

Comment: This doesn't handle the connection or command objects properly and it is promoting sql injection. It also needs at least a rudimentary check that the table doesn't exist or this is going to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Creating tables in code is not standard and I have no clue why you would want to do that.
But your code needs much improvement, I would start with making a class for all your database operations.
I will code a small example to get you going

```
public partial class MyDatabase
{
    private string _connectionString;

    public MyDatabase(string connectionString)
    {
         _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public void ExecuteSql(string sqlStatement)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
             conn.Open();
             using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement))
             {
                  command.Connection = conn;
                  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
        }
    }
}
```

and now you can use this as often as you need it, for example

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase("your connection string");

    db.ExecuteSql("create table test1 (id int, name varchar(10))");
    db.ExecuteSql("create table test2 (id int, name varchar(10))");
    ....
}
```

This is not a complete solution, there are other things you need to solve.
For example before creating a table you need to check if it not already exists
This example is intended to get you on a better way of doing things then you are doing now